# I am not able reach a particular folder in batch file using windows7,but it is OK in Xp. In XP I used cd <path> to that particular directory

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, cd

I have a batch script which is running perfectly fine in WindowsXP but not in Windows7. I am able to create and copy contents  from one other folder but ,renaming of files in the new folder is not possible...

cd  is not working (path to new folder),actually we are not reaching to the new folder to rename the files..

This is what I have tried.

:: to customize the command prompt

```
         @echo off
```

::start

```
         :createFolder
         set /p folderName= New Folder Name...:
         if exist %folderName% goto :error else :yes
```

:: enter source folder path

```
         set /p fName=Which folder contents are to be copied to the new folder:
```

:: enter destination folder path

```
         set /p path= Location of new folder..:
         cd /d %path%
```

:: creating and copying files to new folder
        cd\
                md %path%\%folderName%

```
         %systemroot%\System32\xcopy  "%fName%" "%path%\%folderName%" /e/h/k/s


        cd  %path%\%folderName%
```

:: Running Batch Rename

```
        set /p pathName=Enter The new pattern:
        set "number= %pathName%"
        set "number=%number:~-8%"

        for %%f in (*.xlsx) do (
            set "file=%%f"
            CALL :renameToNumber

        )
        :renameToNumber


            ren "%file%" %file:~0,-13%%number%.xlsx


        :yes
             echo The folder %folderName% created successfully!

        goto :1
        exit

        :error
             echo The folder %folderName% already exist!
             goto :createFolder
        exit
```

Is CD working in windows7?? If not,
How do I reach to the Particular directory??
Is there any other permission needed??

Comment: You shouldn't use `%path%` as a local variable in your batch file.  It is used by Windows/DOS to set the folders to search when running a program without a fully qualified path.  Open a new CMD Window and type `set path` to see what I mean.

Comment: Also, Windows Vista and above are more strict on the usage of permissions: administrator users do not get full permissions unless the process runs in elevated mode. This may cause issues on software not taking into account this.

Comment: Another thing, try using pushD instead of CD since it will work across drives. CD C:\test\, for example, won't work if the prompt is currently on a different drive letter.

Comment: @bill you can make `cd` also change the drive if you use the `/d` parameter, e.g.: `cd /d d:\temp`

Answer (score 0):

By putting all good comments together, the batch file below should work as long as the user has the required permission to access the folders and create the new folder at all.

```
@echo off
::start
:createFolder
set /p folderName= New Folder Name...:
if exist "%folderName%" goto :error else :yes

:: enter source folder path
set /p fName=Which folder contents are to be copied to the new folder:

:: enter destination folder path
set /p newFolder= Location of new folder..:
cd /d "%newFolder%"

:: creating and copying files to new folder cd\ md %path%\%folderName% 
%systemroot%\system32\xcopy.exe "%fName%" "%newFolder%\%folderName%" /e/h/k/s

cd /d "%newFolder%\%folderName%"

:: Running Batch Rename
set /p pathName=Enter The new pattern:
set "number= %pathName%"
set "number=%number:~-8%"

for %%f in (*.xlsx) do (
    set "file=%%f"
    CALL :renameToNumber
)

:renameToNumber
ren "%file%" "%file:~0,-13%%number%.xlsx"

:yes
echo The folder %folderName% created successfully!

goto :1
exit

:error
echo The folder %folderName% already exist!
goto :createFolder
exit
```